# Add startup program or file in windows10

Tags: windows, boot

I want to add a program to auto run while login to PC. I want to know how to add program to startup in windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with registry keys too.

Per-User (No admin account required): Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and add a string value as the display name of the startup program. Then set its data to the full command line to run the program. Will run only if you log on with your account.

Per-Machine (Admin account required): Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and add a string value as the display name of the startup program. Then set its data to the full command line to run the program. Will run on any user account you log on.